# Using double arrows in a collapse menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use double arrows (on left side and right side) in a collapse menu but I couldn't.

You can find a collapse menu example here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/b47p2

The example I want on https://sedo.com/us/'s "HOW IT WORKS" section.

I tried to solve sedo's codes but I couldn't merge. As much as I understand, they use

```
_transform: rotate(135deg);_
```

to make double arrow.

**The Codes  want to change:**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8" id="main">
            <h3>Doesn't it look better ?</h3>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                      Why is it better
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul>
                      <li>The titles are block, so you don't have to click the text part to activate it</li>
                      <li>Indicators for expand / collapsing items</li>
                      <li>Removed title links' obnoxious :hover  underlinings, and outlines.</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                      Collapsible Group Item #2
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                      Collapsible Group Item #3
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <h3>Compared to default</h3>

            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion_reg" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne_reg">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_reg" href="#collapseOne_reg" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne_reg">
                     Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne_reg" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne_reg">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo_reg">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_reg" href="#collapseTwo_reg" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo_reg">
                      Collapsible Group Item #2
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo_reg" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo_reg">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree_reg">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_reg" href="#collapseThree_reg" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree_reg">
                      Collapsible Group Item #3
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree_reg" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree_reg">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar col-md-4" id="sideright">
            <h3>Sidebar</h3>
            <p class="well">Some sidebar content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
#accordion .panel-heading { padding: 0;}
#accordion .panel-title > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
    outline: none;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#accordion .panel-title > a.accordion-toggle::before, #accordion a[data-toggle="collapse"]::before  {
    content:"\e113";
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    margin-right :1em;
}
#accordion .panel-title > a.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before, #accordion a.collapsed[data-toggle="collapse"]::before  {
    content:"\e114";
}
```

Thank you very much..

Comment: Can you post the code of what you have so far?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: That effect is achieved by two images, you just add JavaScript code to change the images from expanded to collapsed when you click on the title bar.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan  I added the codes, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your css to next

```
#accordion .panel-heading { 
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#accordion .panel-title > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.4em 2em;
    outline: none;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#accordion .panel-title > a.accordion-toggle::before, #accordion a[data-toggle="collapse"]::before,
#accordion .panel-title > a.accordion-toggle::after, #accordion a[data-toggle="collapse"]::after{
    content:"\e113";
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    top: 0.5em;

}
#accordion .panel-title > a.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before, #accordion a.collapsed[data-toggle="collapse"]::before,
#accordion .panel-title > a.accordion-toggle.collapsed::after, #accordion a.collapsed[data-toggle="collapse"]::after{
    content:"\e114";
}
#accordion .panel-title > a.accordion-toggle::before, #accordion a[data-toggle="collapse"]::before,
#accordion .panel-title > a.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before, #accordion a.collapsed[data-toggle="collapse"]::before {
    left: 0.5em;
}
#accordion .panel-title > a.accordion-toggle.collapsed::after, #accordion a.collapsed[data-toggle="collapse"]::after,
#accordion .panel-title > a.accordion-toggle::after, #accordion a[data-toggle="collapse"]::after{
    right: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Georgiy Dubrov. Cool solution. I tried this on bootsnipp.com. It works but after opened the menu, all arrows goes to left. Can you solve this too?

Comment: It works great! Thank you very much. You found a great solution for collapse menus. I think you should add your solution to bootsnipp.com too. Thank you very much again..

Comment: Edit: Hi @georgiy-dubrov and other users, I want to ask a new question to you: If you use more than two lines in panel-title, then right (second) arrow goes to end of the last line (below). I want to see this right arrow on a static point. I tried to use 'vertical-align:top' but it doesn't work. Do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: @user3620931 made changes in css according to your last comment. please take a look

Comment: Hi @georgiy-dubrov , you are amazing. Thank you very much for your helps. Latest codes works great. You should share your solution on bootsnipp.com. I never seen a solution like yours. Thank you very much again...